# Working around StaleElementReference in selenium-webdriver when testing a react component

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, reactjs

I have a fairly basic react component, which renders a button with span containing a number, and a [yadda](https://github.com/acuminous/yadda)/mocha test for it.

*Sometimes* test fails with StaleElementReference - this seems to happen when component is slow to update, so

`driver.findElement(By.css('.button-counter')).then(function(counter) {`

is executed before element is updated, and then naturally

`counter.getText()`

fails.

Seems that a common approach is to try to re-fetch element several times before actually failing the test (like it's done [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/543#issuecomment-37665141)); problem is that in my case no matter how long do I wait, I always get a reference to stale element; feels like `driver.findElement` caches first result somewhere, and always returns that for subsequent fetches within current test case run.

I had the following method at some point, which *should* have worked, but somehow I still was getting StaleElementReferences:

```
function waitForElementWithText(driver, cssSelector, txt, attempts) {
  if (!attempts) {
    attempts = 3;
  }

  // first wait for element to be present
  return driver.findElement(By.css(cssSelector)).then(function(found) {
    // now wait for it to be visible
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(300); // we need this to be faster now
    driver.wait(function() {
      return found.isDisplayed().then(function(visible) {
        // First wait for it to become visible
        if (visible) {
          // Then wait for text to be populated
          return found.getText().then(function(gotTxt) {
            return gotTxt === txt;
          }, function(err) {
            if (attempts > 0) {
              return waitForElementWithText(driver, cssSelector, txt, attempts--);
            }
             throw err;
          });
        }
        driver.sleep(300); // give it a break
        return false;
      }, function(err) { /* err hnd */
        if (attempts > 0) {
          return waitForElementWithText(driver, cssSelector, txt, attempts--);
        }
        throw err;
      });
    }, function(err) {
      if (attempts > 0) {
        return waitForElementWithText(driver, cssSelector, txt, attempts--);
      }
      throw err;
    });
    // restore implicit wait
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000);
  }, function(err) { /* err hnd */
    if (attempts > 0) {
      return waitForElementWithText(driver, cssSelector, txt, attempts--);
    }
    throw err;
  });
}
```

For now I just added a 1-second sleep before doing the first findElement, but that's sub-optimal, of course.
So is there some recommended way of dealing with this case? Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can try [`webDriver.wait`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebDriver.html#wait), you can put your desired state as condition and it returns a promise, if promise resolves, all fine, if rejects, you got a problem.

Comment: Yea, that's what I ended up doing... It's just doesn't feel very right, since button update might take various amount of time, and I would like test to wait until text appears rather than just "wait 15 seconds", for instance.

Comment: That is exactly what wait does,  even if you give 15 seconds,  and  desired result appears in 5, it stops at 5

Answer (score 1):

It is actually best-practice to not store WebElement references to variables unless absolutely necessary.   Instead, store the selector and retrieve the element using the selector whenever it is needed.  This should alleviate most or all of your StaleElementExceptions.

Comment: Yes, but that's exactly what I was doing! I'll update description with method I ended up trying to use to avoid this case, which still had the problem

Comment: actually, according to the code you linked, you're storing the element as a function parameter.